# Securing WCF web services over SSL

Tags: wcf, ssl, web-services

Anyone know of any good articles that describe how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you would usually have to do is set your binding to use transport security, then have IIS set for SSL. That is assuming your using a standard WCF binding and hosted in IIS.

You can google "wcf transport security" or see the main MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733043.aspx

There is also this StackOverflow topic [425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service) that shows a snipit of XML configuration.

If there is a more specific issue, then I can try to help further... Custom bindings or being self-hosted take a little more work.