# How can I use WCF with the basichttpbinding only , SSL and Basic Authentication in IIS?

Tags: wcf, ssl, wcf-binding, wcf-security, basichttpbinding

Is it possible to setup a WCF service with SSL and Basic Authentication in IIS using only the `BasicHttpBinding-binding`? 
(I can’t use the `wsHttpBinding-binding`)

The site is hosted on IIS 7, with the following authentication set up:

- Anonymous access: **OFF**
- Basic authentication: **ON**
- Integrated Windows authentication: **OFF**

---

**Service Config:**

```
<services>
  <service name="NameSpace.SomeService">
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="https://hostname/SomeService/" />
      </baseAddresses>

    </host>
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
              bindingNamespace="http://hostname/SomeMethodName/1"
              contract="NameSpace.ISomeInterfaceService"
              name="Default"
                      />
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <exceptionShielding/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

I tried 2 types of *bindings* with two different errors:

- **1. IIS Error:**

  > 'Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].

  ```
  <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding>
         <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
         </security>
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
  ```
- **2. IIS Error:**

  > Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

  ```
   <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
       <binding>
         <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
         </security>
       </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  ```

Does anyone know how to configure this correctly? (*if is it possible?*)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

After some digging and asking some questions to a few colleagues, we finally solved the problem.

Important to understand is there are 2 aspects of security in this case. The IIS security and the WCF security.

**IIS security:** Enable SSL & enable Basic Authentication. Disable Anonymous Authentication.
(Of course, create a windows account/group and set the permissions on your application in IIS.)

**WCF security**: Because the binding is only a BasicHttpBinding, the service doesn't require to valid anything. IIS is responsible for this.

The binding configuration of  the service:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
     <binding>
        <security mode="Transport">
           <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
        </security>
     </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
```

And finally, to resolve the first error, we deleted the mex Endpoint. This endpoint requires a HTTP binding.

Deleted:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for this post. What do you mean by "set the permissions on your application in IIS" ?

Comment: What groups the Windows User Account should be long to? What permissions would need to be set up?

Comment: Why delete `<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>` ?

Comment: you can look at microsoft page to work with SSL setup including setting of permission on IIS. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-configure-an-iis-hosted-wcf-service-with-ssl.