# WCF + Basic Auth - Won't stop using Anonymous Auth

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, basic-authentication

I’ve been trying to create a WCF service that uses Basic Authentication and so far I keep hitting an error message indicating that the service wants Anonymous authentication even though I thought I'd configured the web.config to use Basic auth.

I spent a few hours trying and failing to find a solution to my problem, so I wanted to give it a try here.  I suspect it's something I'm overlooking.

Here's what I'm doing.  I created a web project, added a wcf service, created another web project, and added a single .aspx page to test the service.  I didn’t change *ANYTHING* in the default wcf service config.  I can deploy to IIS and if I open a browser window and navigate to the page, the service works fine once I enable anonymous authentication.  I can also use the test page to access the service without any issues.

Then, I changed the service to use basic auth (see below for the service's web.config) and redeployed.  I didn't change IIS's authentication to use Basic, so it was still set to use Anonymous authentication.  I refreshed the browser and the service displayed.  The test web page was still able to access the service.

Then, I changed the authentication scheme in IIS to use Basic and made sure all other types of authentication were disabled.  When I tried to access the service I received the error message, “Security settings for this service require ‘Anonymous’ Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.”

Here is my service’s web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior name="">
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />

      <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicAuthBinding">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="Basic" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
      </bindings>

      <services>
        <service name="TestService">
          <endpoint address="http://localhost:7000/BA.svc" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicAuthBinding" name="BasicEndpoint" />
        </service>
      </services>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Any ideas why this isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Following some suggestions in [How can I use WCF with only basichttpbinding, SSL and Basic Authentication in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904883/how-can-i-use-wcf-with-only-basichttpbinding-ssl-and-basic-authentication-in-iis), can you replace your wsHttpBinding by a basicHttpBinding, set  `<serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />` and enable SSL on your IIS?

Or is this for some reason not the way you want to host your service?