# client/server, encrypted comms

Tags: c#, encryption, client-server

I've got a basic tcp client/server setup going in c#. I'm now trying to encrypt the data going back and forth.  I'm able to send data from the client to the server, have the server run a command, then try to send the results back to the client.  I can get the data from client to server, and the server runs the command.  When the server tries to send results back to client I get an error message on the client that the stream is not readable.  Below is relevant code parts.

Server:

```
    .......
//Create an instance of TcpListener to listen for TCP connection.
    TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, TcpPort);
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            tcpListener.Start();
            //Accept the client if one is found.
            TcpClient TCP = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();
           // Console.WriteLine("Client connected through TCP.");

            //Create a network stream from the connection.
            NetworkStream NetStream = TCP.GetStream();

            //Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class
            // and decrypt the stream.
            RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();


            //Create a CryptoStream, pass it the NetworkStream,  decrypt with the Rijndael class using the key and IV.
            CryptoStream CryptStream = new CryptoStream(NetStream,RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV),CryptoStreamMode.Read);

            //Read the stream.
            StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader(CryptStream);

            //run the command received
            string commandToRun = SReader.ReadToEnd();
            string commandOutput = runCommand(commandToRun);
            Console.WriteLine("output is " + commandOutput);
       //     SReader.Close();

            // now send results back
            CryptoStream CStream_WRITE = new CryptoStream(NetStream, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

            if (CStream_WRITE.CanWrite)
            {
                //Create a StreamWriter for easy writing to the network stream.
                StreamWriter SWriter2 = new StreamWriter(CStream_WRITE);

                //Write to the stream.
                SWriter2.Write(commandOutput, commandOutput.Length);
                Console.WriteLine("writing {0} bytes back ", commandOutput.Length);
                SWriter2.Flush();
                SWriter2.Close();
            }

       //       CStream_WRITE.Close();
      //        NetStream.Close();
      //        TCP.Close();
                tcpListener.Stop();

        } // end while
    }
    //Catch any exceptions. 
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Server Failed");
    }
}
```

And here is the client: ....... The bold line is where I am getting an error

```
        //Create a TCP connection to a listening TCP process.

        TcpClient TCP = new TcpClient(serverName, TCPPORT);

        //Create a network stream from the TCP connection. 
        NetworkStream NetStream = TCP.GetStream();

        //Create a new instance of the RijndaelManaged class
        // and encrypt the stream.
        RijndaelManaged RMCrypto = new RijndaelManaged();

        byte[] Key = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };
        byte[] IV = { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08, 0x09, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16 };

        //Create a CryptoStream, pass it the NetworkStream, and encrypt 
        //it with the Rijndael class.
        CryptoStream CryptStream = new CryptoStream(NetStream, RMCrypto.CreateEncryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        if (CryptStream.CanWrite)
        {
            //Create a StreamWriter for easy writing to the network stream.
            StreamWriter SWriter = new StreamWriter(CryptStream);

            //Write to the stream.
            SWriter.WriteLine(theData);
            SWriter.Flush();
            SWriter.Close();
      //    CryptStream.Close();

            //Inform the user that the message was written to the stream.
            Console.WriteLine("The message was sent.");
        }

        // get response
        **CryptoStream CStreamREAD = new CryptoStream(NetStream, RMCrypto.CreateDecryptor(Key, IV), CryptoStreamMode.Read);**
        if (CStreamREAD.CanRead)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("stream can read\n");
            StreamReader SReader = new StreamReader(CStreamREAD);
            string commandResults = SReader.ReadToEnd();
            Console.WriteLine("receiving {0} bytes from server", commandResults.Length);
            Console.WriteLine("results are " + commandResults)
```

Comment: Please always include the **full** error message itself. Oh, and welcome...

Answer (score 4):

The easiest, and BY FAR the safest, is to implement an already existing protocol, like SSL.  You can use the [SslStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) class to provide security and server authentication, or you can just switch to WCF and not deal with streams at all. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service) is a question on how to enable SSL for WCF. As for just a basic WCF tutorial, there are hundreds.

Rolling your own is likely to be very insecure and error prone.

Comment: Good advice in general, but the poster seems to be doing this for "academic" purposes ...

Comment: Besides, it's simply not an answer to the question, use comments!

Comment: I had considered that, but then I've also seen so many things that are "academic" turn into production software, so one can never be too careful :)

Comment: I don't know if I agree it's not an answer to the question. But I guess I might have a different view on the purpose of answers. You're exactly right, it doesn't answer his specifically. But I suppose I take the view that for me, I'd rather someone answer what I was trying to do, as opposed to specifically what I asked, since sometimes I don't know enough to even start down the right path. But I'll use comments from now on for those things.

Comment: I would not go that far mfanto - and you did provide a stream answer, so that's fair. I do believe that rolling out your own crypto is insecure in general, but creating a PKI can be daunting as well (secret keys auth is not implemented in .net, so it would have to be self signed certs, possibly with client authentication).

Comment: sorry - the full error message is below. I will try SSL, but would really like to get what I have running.  I am learning C# so would like to understand how to encrypt a stream both ways.

Comment: Error message:

System.ArgumentException: Stream was not readable.
Parameter name: stream
   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptoStream..ctor(Stream stream, ICryptoTran
sform transform, CryptoStreamMode mode)
   at secureClient.tcpClient(String serverName, String theData) in C:\src\secure
Server\secureClient\secureClient.cs:line 62 Exception caught.

Answer (score 0):

StreamWriter.close() also closes the underlying stream, which closes CryptoStream, which closes the underlying socket as per API.

At least, that'm my guess as experienced Java developer :)