# C# WCF TCP Security vs Performance

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, tcp

I'm currently developing a little server-client based game in my free time, using C# and WCF with net.TCP.
To let you understand my circumstances, here what I did until now:

- The server application hosts a WCF service and client applications connect to it. The clients register callback objects which the server stores in a list and calls methods to push messages to the clients.
- The server service contains methods like `Connect` and `Disconnect` which start/terminate a session automatically. The server then uses the session id and callback object to identify the client and remember it for callbacks.
- The client callback object contains methods like `ObjectCreated`, `PropertyChanged` and so on, which are called by the server when the according server event happens.
- The WCF service has no security configured, which is fine until now. But soon I will extend the service in a way that a client can send control messages, maybe like "menu entry selected" or "moving right". The client can still be identified using the list of clients which called `Connect` and an illegal call could technically be noticed, but I don't know if that is the right way to go.

The next thing to think about is the login with an username and password. First I tried to refactor the `Connect` method to `Connect(string UserName, string Password)`, but I don't think this is a good idea since the password is transfered unencrypted.

So I googled a lot about username / password authentication with WCF, thinking about using a custom `UserNamePasswordValidator` implementation to check if the credentials match an account on the server. But I read you have to use a certificate and per message authentication, which sounds like bad performance to me since there will be a lot of network interaction between the server and the clients.

Now my question: Is there any fast and safe way to log in with username / password (maybe per session) just like in other known client-server based games?

A detailed answer would be a great step for my little game and constructive changes to my strategy are appreciated, thanks a lot.

Comment: You can use a SSL connection to have a fully encrypted transport layer. Than would it be ok to have a `Login(string user, string pwd)`..

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer, how do I set up a SSL connection? I'm using a config file, do I need to specify it there?

Comment: Yes. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service

Comment: Ok, I'm trying to use it in my game. Thanks a lot