# Implementing SSL in WCF

Tags: wcf, ssl, wcf-security, transport-security

I have a small question about SSL implementation with Transport security in wcf.

What i understood from Research is,

- First client makes a request to WCF via https.
- Server will send a public key to client.
- Client uses this public key and encrypts the data and then sends across transoport.
- server receives the encrypted data and decrypts it using private key.

Is there anything wrong in my understanding......?

My second question is
Whats the process when service sends the response back (how encryption and decryption occcurs?).

Thanks in advance

Note: My Question is not about how to implement SSL in WCF, it is how ssl workds both in case of request and response.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable SSL for my WCF service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service)

Comment: no, its not.
I dont want to know how to implement it..I want to clear my understanding about SSL...:)

Comment: My question is how SSL works in case of WCF?