# Enabling SSL for my WCF application is having problems

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

we have developed a WCF webservice and it has been working fine without any requirement of SSL being introduced. Now, before deploying it to Test envirnment we need to make it SSL enabled.

So I came across this link on SO : [Enable SSL for my WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/425978/enable-ssl-for-my-wcf-service)

and changed my config file to include following code:

```
 <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPromotionalSponsorship" allowCookies="true"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            maxBufferSize="20000000"
            maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
           maxArrayLength="200000000"
           maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
         <security mode="Transport">              
         </security>
       </binding>
```

While my endpoint looks like following

```
 <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IPromotionalSponsorship"
          name="StandardEndpoint" contract="PL.Commercial.PromoSponsor.Service.Contracts.IPromotionalSponsorship" />
```

But it does not sound like it changed anything still when I run my project, it shows the URL without https.

Now, when i explicitly add 's' in the URl it throws following error:

> Unable to make a secure connection to the server. This may be a
>   problem with the server, or it may be requiring a client
>   authentication certificate that you don't have.

I have created a self-signed certificate and added it to my local IIS. Anything special that I need to change/add?

Comment: what is your endpoint configuration?

Comment: i updated both binding and enpoint in my original question above

Comment: what happend if you add s after http, it works?

Comment: I tried that and added the error that my browser produced into the original question above.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do following changes.

1. If you don't need client authentication and just HTTPS then your binding configuration should look like below. Note transport element.

   ```
    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IPromotionalSponsorship" allowCookies="true"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="20000000"
            maxBufferSize="20000000"
            maxBufferPoolSize="20000000">
     <readerQuotas maxDepth="32"
          maxArrayLength="200000000"
          maxStringContentLength="200000000"/>
     <security mode="Transport">
       <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
     </security>
   </binding>
   ```
2. If you want browser to display https when you browse service. Your service behaviour should look like below.

   ```
   <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
      <behavior>
        <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="True" httpsGetBinding="mexHttpsBinding"/>
      </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   ```
3. If you are getting error "Unable to make a secure connection to the server..." as mentioned in question that means you have configured service in such way that it requires client certificate. I guess you just need to enable HTTPS. In that case you don't need to configure client certificate requirement in IIS.
   Your application's SSL settings should look like this.
   [image]

Comment: If you do need client cert authentication then read this document.  http://dotnetdevblog.blogspot.com/2010/08/setting-up-client-certificate.html

Comment: I added the self-sgned cert following instructions here: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-enabling-ssl-on-iis7-using-self-signed-certificates without any luck on this

Comment: @pankaj: Thank for your comments. I still did not #3 of your answer. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: OK, I think this is in IIS. However, I am not mapping my service to iis. I am using regular Visual Studio IIS Express. Does this setting apply there?